# Using localStorage to store the maximum and minimum values of jQuery range slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, cookies, local-storage

Please take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kbrqb/121/).

I use `localstorage` in `stop: function (event, ui)` to store each slider's value, but the console shows that it only stores the last single value. Is there a way to store the last maximum and minimum values of each slider ,or in other words, the last value of every `ui-slider-handle`?

HTML:

```
<h4> Width</h4>
<div data-max="100" data-min="0" class="slider"></div>
<input type="text" class="center amount">
<h4> Diameter</h4>
<div data-max="50" data-min="0" class="slider"></div>
<input type="text" class="center amount">
<h4> Thickness</h4>
<div data-max="20" data-min="0" class="slider"></div>
<input type="text" class="center amount">
```

Jquery:

```
$( ".slider" ).each(function(){
  var datamax = $(this).data('max'),
      datamin = $(this).data('min'),
      amount = $(this).next('.amount'),
      $key = $(this).prev('h4').text();

  $(this).slider({

     range: true,
     min: 0, 
     max: datamax,    
     values: [ datamin, datamax ],    
     slide: function( event, ui ) {       
       amount.val( ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] +" mm");           
     },
     stop: function (event, ui) {
        localStorage[$key] = ui.value;
      }    
     });

     amount.val($( this ).slider( "values", 0 ) +" - " + $( this ).slider( "values", 1 )  +" mm");

});
```

Comment: please be more specific what you consider min/max values. I can think of several interpretations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kbrqb/122/)   try  this,

```
     localStorage[$key] = ui.value+ " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] +" mm";
```